# itunes search ruby gem: uninitialized constant Itunes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Using this [itunes search](http://github.com/johnnyiller/itunes-search) gem, and the documentation seems really straightforward. It fails
with

> NameError: uninitialized constant Itunes

```
gem install itunes-search

Usage

base = Itunes::Base.new

search_object = base.search("term"=>"The Killers")

# get an array of the search_objects

results = search_object.results

results.each do |result|
   puts result.trackViewUrl
end

puts result.attributes
```

Here is my code

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'itunes-search'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> base = Itunes::Base.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Itunes
from (irb):3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developer might have change the Module name or written incorrect documentation as you should do:

```
base = ItunesSearch::Base.new
```

instead of:

```
base = Itunes::Base.new
```

because the module is name ItunesSearch and not Itunes. That should work :)